# Intermittent OpenSSL Error 0A000126 running Mosquitto MQTT Broker

Tags: openssl, mqtt, tls1.2, mosquitto

We have a customer using:

- OpenSSL 3.1.0 14 Mar 2023 (Library: OpenSSL 3.1.0 14 Mar 2023)
- TLS 1.2
- Mosquitto MQTT Broker
- nginx is not being used

Getting intermittent errors. Here's an example of the MQTT Broker log with the error in it.

```
Nov 09 22:53:25 medius-g2-3865 mosquitto[443]: 1699570405: New connection from 192.168.100.253:47154 on port 8883.
Nov 09 22:53:25 medius-g2-3865 mosquitto[443]: 1699570405: New client connected from 192.168.100.253:47154 as VLUCADBMV07063 (p2, c1, k60).
Nov 09 22:53:25 medius-g2-3865 mosquitto[443]: 1699570405: OpenSSL Error[0]: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading
Nov 09 22:53:25 medius-g2-3865 mosquitto[443]: 1699570405: Client VLUCADBMV07063 closed its connection.
Nov 09 22:53:25 medius-g2-3865 mosquitto[443]: 1699570405: New connection from 192.168.100.253:47155 on port 8883.
Nov 09 22:53:25 medius-g2-3865 mosquitto[443]: 1699570405: New client connected from 192.168.100.253:47155 as VLUCADBMV07063 (p2, c1, k60).
Nov 09 22:53:27 medius-g2-3865 mosquitto[443]: 1699570407: Client VLUCADBMV07063 disconnected: Protocol error.
Nov 09 22:53:27 medius-g2-3865 mosquitto[443]: 1699570407: New connection from 192.168.100.253:47157 on port 8883.
```

Everything will be going along fine, no communication problems, nothing, and then this problem arises, but we're not sure why. Any ideas? Please let me know if you need more information.

Not sure what to try or where to look.

Comment: Can you please provide some info about the client (`192.168.100.253`), network and how you are resolving this (does it resolve itself, or are you restarting something?). It appears that the client is connecting (the CONNECT packet is getting through) and then the connection is dropping. Have you spotted any patterns (is this happening at a regular interval, does it happen when a larger than normal message is published etc).

Comment: IMO this looks like a possible networking issue.  I'd also check the system clocks to make sure they're not off.  Does the problem only happen with the one system in your posted logs, or are other systems also seeing the same problem?